# One-to-many relation. Single 'one' is not an entity

Tags: database, oop, database-design, symfony

In my project I has following entities:
ProjectCategory and Banner

Banner is linked to category by category_id. So one  category has several banners.

The problem is that in addition to categories I have single(currently single) page, where I also need to insert banner.

Currentl I have several solutions:

1. Unlink banner from category, check constraint by code, category_id -1 means this cms page. Good, but constraint isn't checked. Do we need constraint?
2. Unlink banner from category, create Pages table. Page might be as category, so as simple page. Additional table, single page will propably stay single.
3. Add parameter to table like is_homepage. Attach banner to random category. Cascade problem might occure.

What is the best soltion?

P.S. My tools are symfony2.0 and doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to have both `category_id` (NULL-able<sup>1</sup> FK towards Category) and `page_id` (NULL-able FK towards Page) in the Banner. You can either allow or restrict (via a CHECK) the possibility of the same banner belonging to both a category and a page.

To enforce (at most) single banner per page, make `page_id` an alternate key (UNIQUE constraint).

With all of the above, your model would look like:

[image]

```
CHECK (
    (CATEGORY_ID IS NOT NULL AND PAGE_ID IS NULL)
    OR (CATEGORY_ID IS NULL AND PAGE_ID IS NOT NULL)
)
```

---

*<sup>1</sup> DBMS skips NULL when checking for foreign key violations.*

Comment: Well it seems best solution. But it means new Entity - Page. Unfortunately, as far as it goes there will be only single page - homepage %) I will think of yours, it might be that I will make field nullable, and if field has null it would mean that this is homepage. I understand that this is not a good solution :))) But I don't want to mess with add. Entity because of 1 page.